# Failed to build wheel for h5py , in JETSON NANO

Tags: tensorflow, h5py, nvidia-jetson-nano

I have a Nano Jetson and flashed it with the latest available Jetpack version from here: https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/learn/get-started-jetson-nano-devkit which is 4.6.1. Now when following this guide to install tensorflow:
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/official-tensorflow-for-jetson-nano/71770
I was not able to install h5py, I got:
**ERROR: Could not build wheels for h5py, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects** ,
Then, I followed instruction from :
https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/install-tf-jetson-platform/index.html
and tried to build specific version of h5py==3.6.0, I got an error:

**ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement h5py==3.6.0 (from versions: 2.2.1, 2.3.0b1, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.4.0b1, 2.4.0, 2.5.0, 2.6.0, 2.7.0rc2, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0, 2.10.0, 3.0.0rc1, 3.0.0, 3.1.0)**

**ERROR: No matching distribution found for h5py==3.6.0,**

Then I tried with h5py=3.0.0, once again I got the error,

**ERROR: Could not build wheels for h5py, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects**

I have included the complete error log file, Please advice

```
agv@agv-nano:~$ sudo pip3 install -U numpy==1.19.4 future mock keras_preprocessing keras_applications gast==0.2.1 protobuf pybind11 cython pkgconfig packaging h5py==3.6.0
Keyring is skipped due to an exception: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoServer: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-Uj0zn9M8en: Connection refused
WARNING: The directory '/home/agv/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you should use sudo's -H flag.
Collecting numpy==1.19.4
  Downloading numpy-1.19.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2014_aarch64.whl (12.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 12.2 MB 4.5 MB/s            
Collecting future
  Downloading future-0.18.3.tar.gz (840 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 840 kB 4.8 MB/s            
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting mock
  Downloading mock-5.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (30 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: keras_preprocessing in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (1.1.2)
Collecting keras_applications
  Downloading Keras_Applications-1.0.8-py3-none-any.whl (50 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 50 kB 5.6 MB/s            
Collecting gast==0.2.1
  Downloading gast-0.2.1.tar.gz (10 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (3.19.6)
Collecting pybind11
  Downloading pybind11-2.10.4-py3-none-any.whl (222 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 222 kB 3.5 MB/s            
Requirement already satisfied: cython in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.29.33)
Collecting pkgconfig
  Downloading pkgconfig-1.5.5-py3-none-any.whl (6.7 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (21.3)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement h5py==3.6.0 (from versions: 2.2.1, 2.3.0b1, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.4.0b1, 2.4.0, 2.5.0, 2.6.0, 2.7.0rc2, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0, 2.10.0, 3.0.0rc1, 3.0.0, 3.1.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for h5py==3.6.0
agv@agv-nano:~$ sudo pip3 install -U numpy==1.19.4 future mock keras_preprocessing keras_applications gast==0.2.1 protobuf pybind11 cython pkgconfig packaging h5py==3.0.0
Keyring is skipped due to an exception: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoServer: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-Uj0zn9M8en: Connection refused
WARNING: The directory '/home/agv/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you should use sudo's -H flag.
Collecting numpy==1.19.4
  Downloading numpy-1.19.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2014_aarch64.whl (12.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 12.2 MB 4.0 MB/s            
Collecting future
  Downloading future-0.18.3.tar.gz (840 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 840 kB 6.6 MB/s            
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting mock
  Downloading mock-5.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (30 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: keras_preprocessing in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (1.1.2)
Collecting keras_applications
  Downloading Keras_Applications-1.0.8-py3-none-any.whl (50 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 50 kB 2.1 MB/s            
Collecting gast==0.2.1
  Downloading gast-0.2.1.tar.gz (10 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (3.19.6)
Collecting pybind11
  Downloading pybind11-2.10.4-py3-none-any.whl (222 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 222 kB 2.0 MB/s            
Requirement already satisfied: cython in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.29.33)
Collecting pkgconfig
  Downloading pkgconfig-1.5.5-py3-none-any.whl (6.7 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (21.3)
Collecting h5py==3.0.0
  Downloading h5py-3.0.0.tar.gz (370 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 370 kB 4.3 MB/s            
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting cached-property
  Downloading cached_property-1.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from keras_preprocessing) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=3.0.5,>=2.0.2 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from packaging) (2.2.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: gast, h5py, future
  Building wheel for gast (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for gast: filename=gast-0.2.1-py3-none-any.whl size=7472 sha256=488c76a4bf32dc0e35d0018bdc73da4fb502982c8effdb5ff8b648a526edfea2
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-p8stowdg/wheels/5a/de/13/ce88a752efbdba27fa15e3047f3445128e76d6c1a1197a9d5c
  Building wheel for h5py (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status -4:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 /home/agv/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmprpijrfus
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-dlr53off/h5py_f9c68c630e724b9c8225257c47447da2
  Complete output (67 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py
  copying h5py/version.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py
  copying h5py/_init_.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py
  copying h5py/ipy_completer.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py
  copying h5py/h5py_warnings.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/hl/init_.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/base.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/filters.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/group.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/attrs.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/datatype.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/files.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/dataset.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/dims.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/vds.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/selections2.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/selections.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/_hl
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/conftest.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_attribute_create.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_errors.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_file_image.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_attrs.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/_init_.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_h5pl.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_dataset_swmr.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_attrs_data.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/common.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_dims_dimensionproxy.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_h5p.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_big_endian_file.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_datatype.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_filters.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_objects.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_dimension_scales.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_h5f.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_file.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_h5d_direct_chunk.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_h5t.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_group.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_selections.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_slicing.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_dtype.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_completions.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_dataset.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_base.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_h5.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_dataset_getitem.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_file2.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests/data_files
  copying h5py/tests/data_files/_init_.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests/data_files
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests/test_vds
  copying h5py/tests/test_vds/_init_.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests/test_vds
  copying h5py/tests/test_vds/test_virtual_source.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests/test_vds
  copying h5py/tests/test_vds/test_highlevel_vds.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests/test_vds
  copying h5py/tests/test_vds/test_lowlevel_vds.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests/test_vds
  copying h5py/tests/data_files/vlen_string_dset.h5 -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests/data_files
  copying h5py/tests/data_files/vlen_string_dset_utc.h5 -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests/data_files
  copying h5py/tests/data_files/vlen_string_s390x.h5 -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/h5py/tests/data_files
  running build_ext
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for h5py
  Building wheel for future (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for future: filename=future-0.18.3-py3-none-any.whl size=492037 sha256=79c240fc12311f694c4be36da939fd21f541504398cd24eaa651badc9f9e4efe
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-p8stowdg/wheels/63/f1/0c/e56d12b3804345ce5ba34279cbfe583ecafdd1401551457330
Successfully built gast future
Failed to build h5py
ERROR: Could not build wheels for h5py, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the commands below:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
$ sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev hdf5-tools libhdf5-dev 
$ pip3 install cython
$ pip3 install h5py==2.10.0
```

These commands were originally posted on the Nvidia Forums.
But my jetson wasn't working, so I ran them and now it worked.

```
$ export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/cuda/bin
```